# Upload path/URL weirdness for the main blog of a multisite/network setup

Tags: multisite, uploads, media

We have a WP network (with domain mapping) that was started pre WP 3.5, so it was using `ms-files.php` and `wp-content/blogs.dir/` to store media files. I wanted to remove `ms-files.php` dependency and after doing some research started the process:

I first tried not *moving* any files from `blogs.dir/#/files` to `uploads/sites/#`, but to setup symlinks for that. Then I had some permissions issues so I just copied everything from `blogs.dir/#/files` to `uploads/sites/#`.

Then I cleared the values for `upload_path`, `upload_url_path` and `fileupload_url` on each site.

And finally updated/inserted `ms_files_rewriting = 0` in the `wp_sitemeta` table.

Also added some rewrite rules to the `.htaccess` file to not have to deal with updating all URLs in DB.

The main blog id in our setup is 2 and not the default which is 1: `define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);`

As far as I know, and based on what I see in `wp_upload_dir()`, WP uses the root of the `uploads` folder for the main blog contents and `uploads/sites/#` for other blogs. So I have copied the content from `blogs.dir/2/files` to the root of the `uploads` folder and NOT to `uploads/sites/2`.

Now here is the issue for media files on the MAIN BLOG: in the back-end, WP loads files from the `uploads` folder which is fine, but on the front-end it tries to load files from `uploads/sites/2` which doesn't exist and is weird!

PS: I can just add another rewrite rule to have this fixed, but I really want to know what the reason is for `/sites/2` being added for the main blog.

Comment: I've arrived at the same sort of problem via a different path. After migrating to a new hosting provider (and making a few tweaks along the way) I'm also seeing the back-end work fine but the front-end using the the blogs.dir directory for the main site.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress multisite's "Upload Path" should be set to a server-relative path (e.g. `/home/serveraccountname/public_html/wp-content/uploads`).

The "Upload URL Path" should be the URI (e.g. `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads`).

Ignore the `/sites/1/` fragment for sub-sites - WordPress will add these automatically.

Answer (score 0):

We used to be able to set the directory where files were kept and that option was removed so this might have something to do with the misdirected links. I had the same problem, but I went through and reuploaded the files that weren't working properly. This might not be realistic if you have lots of files but it is one option. Another option is to use a plugin like **Broken Link Checker** by Janis Elsts. It will search your site for links that don't work and it gives you the option to easily change the URLs. It will also send you an email and tell you if any other site connected to a link stops working. It is very useful and I use it on most of my websites now. ^^